# compare values in columns R

Tags: r, comparison, rows

please look at the following dataframe as a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(Last_year = c('2013', '2020', '2017', '2015', '2016', '2021'), 
year = c('2021', '2020', '2019', '2018', '2017', '2016'))
```

I want to compare the values in the columns and discard the row if the **value is different & Last_year<year**.

This is the code I come up with:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if((df1$Last_year[i] != df1$year[i] && df1$Last_year[i] < df1$year[i]) | 
         is.na(df1$year[i]))
         {df <- df[-i,]}
    else 
         next}
```

I cannot understand why, this code does not eliminate all the last_year < year.. can you spot the reason?

The final dataframe I wish to obtain is:

```
df <- data.frame(Last_year = c('2020', '2021'), 
year = c('2020', '2016'))
```

which correspond to the second and the last values, which are the one that satisfy my wish --> Last_year > year

Comment: `df[df$Last_year < df$year, ]`

Comment: @Maël could you please tell me where I should put your code? In the "if" condition it doesn't work

Comment: Nowhere in the loop. This works by itself

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Maël's contribution, it seems you want to keep rows which last_year is greater than year:

```
df[df$Last_year > df$year, ]
```

If you want to avoid NAs, you can use `which()`:

```
df[which(df$Last_year < df$year), ]
```

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by ""if the value is different"? Diffrerent to what?

Comment: my dataframe is made of the column last_year which shows the last available year of a bank in the database I used, then I have the column year which I created when I reshaped my dataframe from wide to long.  Since I want to take off columns with NA's in almost all the row, I do a double check in the if condition: if the value in the columns is different (e.g. last_year[i] = 2013 & year[i] = 2020) and last_year < year, discard the row. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Re-check my answer, I've made changes.

Comment: so, should I put the code you wrote in the if condition?

Comment: Yes. If you quant to overwrite the original df keeping just those rows, you should assign that expression to df.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop at all. You can just replace the for loop with a simple `filter` statement from `dplyr` or use base R as provided by the others.

```
library(dplyr)
    
df %>%
  filter(Last_year >= year  & !is.na(year))
```

Or use `subset` from base R:

```
subset(df, Last_year >= year  & !is.na(year))
```

**Output**

```
  Last_year year
1      2020 2020
2      2021 2016
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Last_year = c("2013", "2020", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2021", "2022"), year = c("2021", "2020", "2019", "2018", 
"2017", "2016", "NA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AndrewGB ! But actually I want to obtain the datafram with the second and last row of my dataframe, cause as said below in another answer: my dataframe is made of the column last_year which shows the last available year of a bank and the column year which I created when I reshaped my dataframe from wide to long.  I do a double check in the if condition: if the value in the columns is different (e.g. last_year[i] = 2013 & year[i] = 2020) and last_year < year, discard the row.

Comment: sure, I did it :) hope it's more clear now

Comment: yes, exactly! Thanks so much!!!! @AndrewGB